# How to run middleware on all routes except static assets

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to run middleware on all express routes except for static assets?

I tried running it right in the `app.use('/', authenticate, app.router());` but that leads to it running for all static assets as well.

Would I just have to list it on all my routes?

Comment: Add this middleware _after_ the `express.static` middleware

Comment: You're right! I was under the impression that static had to come last (before error middleware).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Explosion Pills points out in the comments,

> add your middleware after the `express.static` middleware

Sample codes as below

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(root, './build/client')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true});

// ...
app.use('/', authenticate, app.router());
```